# Upgrading react-scripts gives error on running react-scripts start

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

After updating react-scripts to version `3.4.0` and on running `react-scripts start` in windows I get this error:

```
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Projects\myproject\frontend\src\setupProxy.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Projects\myproject\frontend\src\setupProxy.js from C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Projects\myproject\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpackDevServer.config.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename setupProxy.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Projects\myproject\frontend\package.json.
```

And this is the file `setupProxy`:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  const proxyTarget = process.env.REACT_APP_API || 'http://localhost:8089';
  console.log(`proxying /backend/api/* to ${proxyTarget}/backend/*`);
  app.use(proxy('/backend/api', { target: proxyTarget}));
};
```

Why do I get this error after upgrading `react-scripts`, and it only displays on windows, if I run the same command on mac, then I don't get this error. How can I fix this for windows?